# AWS CDK: Moving resources between stacks

Tags: aws-cdk

Is it possible to move a DB from one Stack to another? Here is the example:

```js
export class ParentStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const dynamodbTable = new dynamodb.TableV2(this, "Name", {
      tableName: "aName",
      partitionKey: { name: "sessionID", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      sortKey: { name: "timestamp", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
    });
  }
}
```

But I want to move the DB down to another class to have the following result:

```js
export class ParentStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new ChildStack(this, "ChildStack")
  }
}
```

I have tried to simply move:

```js
const dynamodbTable = new dynamodb.TableV2(this, "Name", {
  tableName: "aName",
  partitionKey: { name: "sessionID", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
  sortKey: { name: "timestamp", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
});
```

into `ChildStack`, but the best that I manage to get was my modification complaining that the DB already exists with this name.

The two approaches that I can see are:

- leaving the creation of the DB in the parent and passing down its reference to the children
- call the DB as follow `dynamodb.TableV2.fromTableName(scope, id, "aName");` (if deleted from CDK)

I'm wondering if there is alternative way to get closer to what I want to do.

Comment: It depends on how you want to consume the resulting construct.  What's your goal?

Comment: Also, you may wish to reconsider the parent-child stack setup.  See the CDK best practice [Model with constructs, deploy with stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-constructs-model).

Comment: @fedonev nested stacks would fall into the "modelling with stacks" paradigm which is not what that page recommends. Tight-coupling of stacks is an anti-patternnthat makes CFN changes far more difficult down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this manually using the AWS CLI or Console:

- Ensure the table's `RetentionPolicy` is set to `RETAIN` so it isn't deleted after being removed from a stack.
- Remove it from the existing stack (this may also include resolving validation errors such as dependencies)
- Import the resource into the new stack.
- Retry your CDK deployment

EDIT:

[AWS Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html)

["You can manage your resources using AWS CloudFormation regardless of where they were created without having to delete and re-create them as part of a stack."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

[A CDK step-by-step example with](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import)

Comment: My only concern with that approach is that you can't anymore do changes to the DB through the CDK and have to do through either AWS CLI or Console, but that may be the only option that I have

Comment: Once you complete the steps above, if you move the table to the new stack in your CDK and run a deployment they should be in sync (or check with `cdk diff`) and you can make new changes in your CDK.

Comment: @ThomasBoudreau no, it will just be a read-only reference. The resource will no longer be managed by cloudformation.

Comment: @gshpychka That's not true: "You can manage your resources using AWS CloudFormation regardless of where they were created without having to delete and re-create them as part of a stack." [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

Comment: @gshpychka this is great, thank you so much!

@ThomasBoudreau, it would be read-only if you are using `dynamodb.TableV2.fromTableName(scope, "ImportedTable", "NameOfTable" )` but you can have full control if instead, you can use "cdk import" here is an example step by step that worked for me: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import

Comment: @user3045808 you've got us switched, I (Thomas) gave you the answer, gshpychka made the comment that it would be read-only.

Comment: For some reason I was sure the answer included the `fromTableName` code, apologies for the confusion on my part. Yes, CloudFormation import would work.